# SQL Server integration services deployment wizard port

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2014

I am trying to deploy a SSIS project from Visual Studio (VS). I can run my packages locally in VS against the SQL Server 2014 instance. I can also connect to the SQL Server 2014 instance via SQL Server Management Studio.

However, I cannot connect when I try to deploy. Maybe a port needs to be opened for the integration services catalog? Does anyone know the port?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link should give you everything you need about setting up your firewall to work with SSIS and its service. The port it uses seems to be port 135

[Configure a Windows Firewall for Access to the SSIS Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137861.aspx)